# Как указать параметры своей функции в Python?

Tags: python, функции, параметры

Мне нужно написать программу, выводящую на экран текст, введенный пользователем. Выводимый текст должен находиться между строками, образованными символами '#', а длина этих строк должна соответствовать длине введенного текста. Чтобы пометить линии, нужно создать функцию с именем line(lenght).

Я сделал так:

```
userText = input("Введите текст:")
n = len(userText)

def line():
    print("#" * n, userText, "#" * n)
line()
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при использовании функции в параметрах можно было указать количество решеток (перед и после строки) числом или переменной?

Answer (score 0):

потратьте 5 минут своего времени и почитайте про функции

```
def line(text, w1 = -1, w2 = -1):
    n = len(text)
    print('#' * (n if w1 != -1 else w1), text, '#' * (n if w2 != -1 else w2))
```

например так